# JSF2.0 URL problems - Images from within JavaScript resources

Tags: javascript, resources, jsf-2

I am new to JSF and I've looked for 2 days to solve this problem.

I have a Tomcat server with the following folder structure:

```
...
  project_name
    jfs
       ...
       analysis.xhtml
       reports
          reports.xhtml
    resources
       javascript
          parameterPanel.js
       images
          loading.png
```

In analysis.xhtml and reports.xhtml files I added the parameterPanel.js like this:

```
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="parameterPanel.js"/>
```

In parameterPanel.js I'm using that loading.png...**How should I write the URL to that png?**

I've tried like this:

- 'url(../resources/images/loading.png)' - analysis found the png, reports doesn't
- 'url(../../resources/images/loading.png)' - reports found the png, analysis doesn't

Or is there another solution for this problem?

I'm a bit confused...

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly are you setting the `url()`? In a CSS file, or a JS file, or a XHTML file? What's the concrete functional requirement after all?

Comment: in my JS file: parameterPanel.js

Comment: Okay. And the functional requirement?

Comment: the url to loading.png is different depending where the JS file is used: /jsf/analysis.xhtml or /jsf/reports/reports.xhtml and the png in not found. (sorry my english). The path should be: /project/resources/images/loading.png and it is /project/jsf/analysis/loading.png (when parameterPanel.js is used in analysis.xhtml)

Comment: No.. You're describing the problem. I am asking for the functional requirement of the code you've there in JS to display the image. What is that JS doing? Why are you showing the image by JS?

Comment: It's a collapsable panel that collapses when a button is pressed...that button and other things have icons. sample code: `function toggleParametersPanel() {
  $('parameterButtonImage').style.backgroundImage = _isOpen ? 'url(images/parameter/parameter_button_doubleArrow_down.png)' : 'url(images/parameter/parameter_button_doubleArrow_up.png)';
  _isOpen = !_isOpen;
  new Fx.Slide('parameterPanelContent').toggle();
}`

Comment: Thank you. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify those images by CSS instead.

`/resources/css/style.css`

```css
.parameterButtonImage {
    background-image: url(#{resource['images/parameter/parameter_button_doubleArrow_down.png']});
}

.parameterButtonImage.open {
    background-image: url(#{resource['images/parameter/parameter_button_doubleArrow_up.png']});
}
```

*(I assume that the HTML element in question has a `class="parameterButtonImage"`)*

Load it by:

```xml
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
```

*(this way JSF will take care about resolving `#{resource}` paths)*

Modify your JS as follows (assuming MooTools):

```
function toggleParametersPanel() { 
    $('parameterButtonImage').toggleClass('open');
    new Fx.Slide('parameterPanelContent').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write your URL's relative like this

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/loading.png" />
```

Comment: you mean that in my /*.xhtml files I should invoke javascript like this?: `<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/javascript/parameterPanel.js" type="text/javascript"/>`